# Load group layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers 3 and i need to load a Geoserver group-layer

In OL2 i used a code like this and it worked:

```
var layer_group = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "Sample Layer Group",
        "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms",
        {layers: "layer_group_name", transparent: true},
        {isBaseLayer: false, visibility: false}
    );
    map.addLayers([layer_group]);
```

I have no idea how OL3 loads a group.. simple layers he can load correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OL3 API is changed. You could check [examples](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/).

[Explore this one.](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/wms-image.html)

```
var layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
  }),
  new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219]
    })
  })
];
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View2D({
    center: [-10997148, 4569099],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

Comment: For me, the missing part was the 'topp:' in 'topp:states'
I wrote it without it and the layer failed to draw